# Parse formatted text with 2 delimiters to generate two arrays

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, text-parsing, preg-split

I have a little problem I need to sort. I want to either remove a part of a string or split it.

What I want to end up doing is splitting into 2 variables where I have "One, Two, Three" and "1, 2, 3" , I'm not sure if I can split it into two or if I have to remove the part after "-" first then do it again to remove the bit before "-" to end up with two variables. Anyways I have had a look and seems that `preg_split()` or `preg_match()` may work, but have no idea about `preg` patterns.

This is what I have so far :

```
$string = 'One-1, Two-2, Three-3';
$pattern = '????????????';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

EDIT: Sorry my Question was worded wrong:

Basically if someone could help me with the `preg` pattern to either split the Values so I have an array of One, Two Three and 1, 2, 3

### ----------------EDIT--------------

I have another question if I can, how would the preg_match change if I had this
:

`One Object-1, Two Object-2`

So that now I have more than one word before the "-" which want to be stored together and the "1" on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$string = 'One-1, Two-2, Three-3';
$pattern = '/(?P<first>\w+)-(?P<second>\w+)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches['first']);
print_r($matches['second']);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => One [1] => Two [2] => Three ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Comment: Ahh, I tryed to simplify my question but created a wrong question :/ sorry! it, but I actually have an array which is One-1, Two-2, Three-3. And I want to end up with two arrays of One Two Three, and 1 2 3. Sorry for any confusion, I have used explode to split in into One-1 and Two-2 etc etc.

Comment: @user2194556 : your issue fixed ?

Comment: @user2194556 : Edited the answer as per your edit in your question.

Comment: I have another question if I can, how would the preg_match change if i had this "One Object-1, Two Object-2" So that know I have more that one word before the "-" which want to be stored together and the "1" on its own?

Comment: @user2194556 : try this : `$pattern = '/(?P<first>([^,].*?))-(?P<second>\d+)/';` I have not tested it.

Comment: Seems to work great, thank you soooo much again! You are a superstar.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a "-" use this instead:

```
$string = "One-1";
$args = explode("-", $string);
// $args[0] would have One
// $args[1] would have 1
```

You can read more about this function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[^-]+
```

But why use regexp at all? You can simply explode by "-"